# Root file not defined installing from VM

Tags: virtualization

I installed an oracle VM on my machine and when I loaded an Ubuntu ISO it gave me options of trying Ubuntu or installing Ubuntu my first issue is I want to install on another partition I have made not my C, when I tried installing it gave options of side-by-side or the entire disk I want side by side but if I asked to installed I get this error:

```
no root file system defined please correct this from the partitioning menu
```

Please it important that I don't want to install on my C drive. ( the partition's file system is NTFS in case its important )

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu inside the VM?

Answer (score 0):

So, you boot Windows, start the VM booting from Ubuntu ISO (with no virtual hard disk) and are wanting to install to a second partition on your real hard drive?

This would be a very advanced use of VirtualBox but I doubt it would work; it's certainly not a supported or standard use of a VM.

Think of the VM as a completely separate PC. If it hasn't got a (virtual) hard disk, it can't install Ubuntu because, as it reports, there's nowhere to put a root file system. Because it's effectively a separate PC, it can't see the host PC's disk so cannot see that.

Either connect up a virtual disk and install it to the VM or find some way to copy the ISO to a USB drive or CD and use that the boot the real PC to install it in dual boot mode.

Comment: Problem i need to use ruby and its not installing on the VMs but when i used wubi on my second system (windows 7) it installed nicely and ruby came preinstalled but i don't want to have to shut down one OS to use another since i have another machine with windows XP that i rarely used(but want to maintain my XP tho) so i ll try the USB thing else am stuck.

Comment: Still not sure why you don't just give the VM a virtual hard disk in the second partition and just run Ubuntu in a VM, then you wouldn't need to switch OS to use another. You can use shared folders to let the VM access files on the host system.

Comment: i have done that but my fear is since the VM is installed on windows 7 if windows 7 crashes it means am loosing everything including all my work in ubuntu. or am i wrong?

Comment: If windows crashes, it's the same as if the VM crashed. If you were in the middle of something, you might lose a bit, but once you reoot windows, you can just restart the VM as well. Although, if you are working in the VM, it's unlikely that Windows will crash; why would you expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced the same issue.You should try returning to the partitioning menu I.e 1 step backward&select the 'erase disk&install ubuntu option'.it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to partition your hard drive...you can use the iso image and try it as you were using a cd, granted you've mounted as a virtual drive first. I'm not quite sure why 12.10 would try and make you partition your hd, but it's incredibly stupid.  You could install a previous version, but be careful where you either download the iso image b/c when you run it it could say that there's not an OS.  Or you can run 12.10 on vmware.  And as soon as go to create a virtual machine and load the iso it will easy install, so you shouldn't have that problem.  If you do, continue to research on either google or bing. Someone will tell you the answer you're looking for. I'm having the same situation, but if i find a way around it or get the answer i'll let you know @user1373670.